# Какой частью речи является слово «один» в конкретном тексте?

Tags: пунктуация, лексика, грамматика, поэзия

Как известно, слово «один»  может относиться к различным частям  речи и иметь разные значения ([ОДИН](https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD). Толковый словарь Ефремовой).

1. Какой частью речи является слово «один» в следующем стихотворном тексте (числительным, местоимением, прилагательным)?

Кем бы ты ни был, мир тебе и свет,
Кем бы ты ни был, грош тебе цена.
**И все равно** ведь где-то в вышине
И для тебя горит звезда **одна**.

Мне кажется, что возможны **такие варианты:** одна звезда (не несколько); единственная звезда, вполне определенная; какая-то звезда (неизвестная, неопределенная).

2. И дополнительный вопрос: Нужно ли  здесь обособлять оборот «и все равно»? Если нужно, то почему?

Comment: В песне пауза делается после "ведь", это как раз показывает, что "и всё равно ведь" сливается в одно словосочетание. А пауза делается по нашим с вами соображениям, но чуть позже (после всего словосочетания).

Comment: Автор строк — Эдмунд Шклярский.

Comment: Он — автор текста?  А вы уверены?

Comment: Как и музыки. Так указано в интернете. А вы что, его знаете?

Comment: Да нет, просто вроде бы читала, что это переработанный текст другого автора. Музыканты же так часто делают – берут что-то за основу и переделывают на свой вкус.

Comment: Может быть, автором текста песни будет считаться автор финальной версии.

Comment: А если автор вообще к этой  группе не имеет отношения, а стихи написаны когда-то раньше?

Comment: *а стихи написаны когда-то раньше* — тогда они должны получить авторские права на этот текст, но авторство меняться не будет. Но он значится автором текста.

Comment: Ладно, я позже поищу этого автора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ударение падает (по задумке автора) на "и всё равно", то запятая нужна (в связи с паузой как следствием), но оно может и не падать. Лучше, когда падает — тогда более художественно. В другом случае оно сливается с "ведь" в одно словосочетание.
Примечание: когда оно примыкает, может улавливаться коннотация, что об этом уже говорили (*а всё равно ведь так получается*).

Думаю, что прилагательным.
[image]

Comment: Спасибо, oleedd! Оформление ответа потрясающее, содержание тоже отчасти радует. Самое ценное – это то, что вы допускаете обособление, здесь я с вами полностью согласна.  Другим придется объяснять долго и  боюсь что напрасно.  О частице ВЕДЬ.  Она может усиливать слово или фразу – здесь, как мне кажется, усиление фразы, а тогда она должна стоять в начале  этой фразы (запятая нужна).  В вашем примере частица усиливает слово ТАК, а не фразу (как  я думаю).  И еще мне кажется, что здесь значение «единственная звезда», если брать прилагательное. Но другие значения (местоимения и  тоже возможны.

Comment: Да, относится ко всей фразе, иначе ударение должно быть на "где-то", а в моём примере можно прочитать по-разному. Но даже без контекста "и всё равно ведь" (без запятой) вызывает у меня вышеуказанную коннотацию. Да, похоже на единственную звезду, иначе значение "некая звезда" (например, *один человек сказал...*), что здесь не к месту (и в таком случае ударение бы падало на "звезда").

Comment: *Звезда горит в небе одна (будучи одной).* Наш же случай. Тут даже похоже на обстоятельство. Да?

Comment: Что ещё интересно, так это то, что при таком порядке числительное указывает на примерное количество: *На небе горело звезды две*. Так что этот вариант отпадает. Можно сказать, что 1 в таких случаях не используется, потому что кто будет сомневаться в количестве 1? Интересно узнать ваше мнение насчёт обстоятельства.

Comment: Не вижу обстоятельства. Здесь двунаправленная связь - согласование со сказуемым и подлежащим. Варианты: Горит одна звезда, горит одинокая звезда.

Comment: Так — да. А в моём примере как-то всё по-другому: *Звезда горит в небе одна (будучи одной).* Даже вопрос *как?* хочется задать (понимаю, что он не очень подходит).

Comment: Так никто не говорит - это ваша фраза?

Comment: Почему? Моя. Звучит норм. Ну да, чуть нестандартно. Так как же в ней с обстоятельством?

Comment: Никак.  Темное это дело. Что-то такое помню, но не отчетливо, надо искать. Сейчас похожий вопрос задам (про двунаправленные связи), посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

1. Думаю, здесь это прилагательное — причём *качественное*!
2. Нет, не нужно. Если не нужно, то, видимо, «почему» отпадает :)

Comment: (1) Вы имеете в виду, что для каждого человека  может быть только единственная  и вполне определенная звезда, да? А можно это выразить с помощью ударения?  Где ударение  в последней строке?  (2) Вот что за народ! Ведь подумала, что  маловероятно, но может быть такой вопрос… Нет, объяснение нужно в любом случае. Пауза чувствуется, ударение падает на слово РАВНО, а дальше частица ВЕДЬ. Думаю, что здесь две фразы.

Comment: *Пауза чувствуется, ударение падает на слово РАВНО,* - а ведь не обязательно. Попробуйте без паузы и ударения. Смысл предложения при этом иной: мол, хоть тебе и грош цена, а и для тебя где-то звезда горит. Каков правильный смысл - надо автора спрашивать.

Comment: Sharon, я читаю последнюю строчку с ударением на *тебя.*

Comment: 1. «Вы имеете в виду, что для каждого человека может быть только единственная и вполне определенная звезда, да? А можно это выразить с помощью ударения?» — думаю, это надо выражать с помощью ОТСУТСТВИЯ ударения на «одна». 2. «Нет, объяснение нужно в любом случае» — потому что здесь это УСИЛИТЕЛЬНАЯ ЧАСТИЦА (синонимичная словосочетаниям «несмотря на это», «тем не менее», «всё-таки», а таковые запятыми не выделяются. Да, я тоже заметил: многим хочется, чтобы «всё равно» было вводным словосочетанием — объясняйте им, что «всё равно» им НИКОГДА не бывает.

Comment: «я читаю последнюю строчку с ударением на тебя» — Артём, я тоже. (Всё равно стихи неважнец :))

Comment: Всем спасибо за комментарии, было интересно узнать ваше мнение. Позже я дам свой ответ, где учту сказанное. А с вами, Егор, будет отдельный разговор.   По поводу стихотворения, которое "неважнец", и по поводу обособления.

Comment: «А с вами, Егор, будет отдельный разговор» — если я захочу (что не факт) :)

Comment: Это метафора, ага? :)) Этот "отдельный разговор" вы прочитаете между строк моего ответа. И спасибо за ваш ответ. –

Answer (score 1):

**1. О стихотворении**

Мы источник веселья — и скорби рудник.
Мы вместилище скверны — и чистый родник.
Человек, словно в зеркале мир — многолик.
Он ничтожен — и он же безмерно велик!

**Омар Хайям**  Переводчик: Г. Плисецкий

Все виденья так мгновенны —
Буду ль верить им?
Но Владычицей вселенной
Я, случайный, бедный, тленный,
Может быть, любим…

**Александр Блок**

Я думаю, что стихотворение «Кем бы ты ни был» раскрывает эту же тему – Человек и Вселенная. Наши чувства не менее глубоки, чем у людей прошлого, но мы более **сдержанны** в их выражении. И еще слова стали **многомерными**.
Они не возвышенны и не символичны, как раньше, нет, – иногда  даже кажутся простыми и заурядными. Но при этом они в большей степени обращены к подсознанию, и оттого читаются неоднозначно, **будто каждый раз – по-новому**.

**2.  О смысле**

***Мир тебе и свет***?  О чем говорит поэт? Загадка! Мир – это, вероятно, и есть Вселенная.

**И звезда – почему одна**? Она единственная? Но мне кажется, что не это. Здесь у слова «одна» скорее местоименное значение (некая звезда), его можно бы вообще пропустить и сказать: и для тебя горит звезда.

**И что за звезда, звезда-близнец**? Может быть, такой метаобраз –  это наша причастность ко всему мирозданию? Пожалуй, словами об этом не скажешь, можно только почувствовать.

**3. Об ударении**

**Для справок**

*В русском языке словесное ударение характеризуется **силой и длительностью**, но есть еще **тоническое** ударение – повышение  или понижение тона в конце фонетической фразы (обычно предложение состоит из двух или более таких  фраз). Также есть понятие **логического ударения**. Слово будет логически выделенным, если ударение смещено с конца фразы на другое слово. Можно ли логически выделить слово в конце фразы? Можно, но только силовым способом.*

С этой точки зрения интересна **стихотворная речь**. Там расстановка тонических ударений определяется **ритмикой** стиха (или музыкальной ритмикой песни), поэтому возможно только **силовое логическое** выделение слов.

Расстановка тонических ударений: Но все равнО ведь // где-то в вышинЕ  // И для тебЯ // горит звезда однА.

Такая расстановка ударений выглядит как естественный фон, так что можно сказать, что **ударений вообще нет**.  Для логического выделения (ударения) используется только силовой метод.

В последней строке можно **силовым способом** выделить три слова: ***тебя, звезда, одна.*** И вот мне кажется, что при значении «некая звезда» желательно подчеркнуть слово ***звезда.*** Иначе слово  ***одна*** будет выделено тоническим ударением, и тогда оно воспринимается как «единственная». Силовое выделение слова ***тебя*** тоже возможно, но тогда просто усиливается смысл сказанного ранее.

**4. Обособление**

Об обособлении сочетания ***но все равно ведь*** (oleedd подсказал).

Послушала еще раз песню... Действительно, частица *ведь* произносится слитно с первой фразой — *но все равно ведь*, поэтому *ведь* относится к *все равно*. И это, я думаю, единственная причина того, что здесь нет обособления. Если частицу отнести ко во второй части, то *но все равно* нужно будет обособить.

**Для справок.** Это сочетание не обязательно должно быть вводным, чтобы его обособили. Я могу обособить любой обстоятельственный оборот, если это позволяет сделать смысл и структура предложения.

Comment: Sharon, я думаю, вы во многом правы, но стихи — это никогда не «тема». Стихи —  не в смысле термина а как предмет анализа — это конкретный текст. Кстати, в нашем случае это текст метрический, что является дополнительным аргументом против обособления: в этом ямбе «ведь» приходится на слабый слог.

Comment: Ладно, читайте стихи и наслаждайтесь. Что вам в них не понравилось? Кстати, какой конкретно там размер?

Comment: ЭТИ стихи читать и наслаждаться?! :)) «Что вам в них не понравилось?» — ничего мне в них не понравилось. «Кстати, какой конкретно там размер?» — я его конкретно упомянул. Ямб.

Comment: А я-то для вас так старалась.... Интересно было бы узнать, чем вы наслаждаетесь.

Comment: *Мир тебе и свет* — это используется как **первое** приветствие (*мир тебе* уж точно). *Мир и свет* выражают благие намерения обращающегося. Смысл "некая звезда" (странно, что вы поменяли своё мнение) возможен **лишь** при ударении на "звезда". Было бы неправильно закладывать его, когда в песне другое ударение, хоть и связанное с метроритмом (который **определяет** логические ударения — они однозначно есть в песнях, как и в любой речи). *Я... может быть любим* — понимаю, что это использовалось в художественных целях, но это нарушение грамматики.

Comment: Даже если это приветствие, то оно тоже что-то обозначает, а не просто поздоровался. Об ударении: послушала песню – там ударение на «горит», да еще оно красном текстом выделено. Разницу между тоническим и логическим ударением я объяснила: на «одна» падает тоническое ударение, а логически (силовым способом) можно выделить другие слова. А к Блоку какие претензии? Я, может быть, любим (Вселенной), это вводное слово.

Comment: Ой, не заметил запятую... Без логического ударения смысл "некая" никто не обнаружит. А про тоническое ничего не понял, здесь, как всегда, нужны примеры, в данном случае — аудио. *Мир и свет* также может означать "здравствуй, мира и света тебе".

Comment: Можно понять и так. Но еще  надо понять художественный замысел поэта в целом, а не отдельные слова и фрагменты текста.  А понять написанное (про тонические ударения) может ученик младших классов, а вы просто не хотите.

Comment: Да проблема не в понимании, а в том, что информации крайне мало. К чему они вообще? Непохоже, что они влияют на смысл. *повышение или понижение тона в конце фонетической фразы* — вот здесь крайне важны аудиопримеры.

Comment: Психологически я вас хорошо понимаю.  Если мне не хочется осваивать какую-то тему, то я не могу этого сделать, хотя знаю, что это нетрудно.    Сознание как бы закрыто для этой информации. но если вы хотите разбираться в интонации, то надо знать хотя  минимальную теоретическую базу. Нельзя пользоваться терминами, если вы не знаете их определения.

Comment: Разбираюсь в практической интонации. А теория здесь не обязательна (если чувствуешь язык), что бы вы ни говорили, разве что для знания терминологии.

Comment: Нет, не согласна. Без теории вас может оспорить каждый первый, а  с теорией вы выглядели бы убедительнее. Я практической интонацией давно занимаюсь, и теория мне очень помогает. Практика тоже очень  важна. Вот даже за последний год я обратила внимание на некоторые особенности, о которых нигде не прочитаешь.

Comment: «А я-то для вас так старалась....» — вижу и благодарен вам. Но текст у песенки всё равно слабый. Впрочем, для песенных текстов это не имеет значения. «Интересно было бы узнать, чем вы наслаждаетесь» — в частности, хорошими СТИХАМИ, — а тексты попсовых песенок, как правило, на стихи похожи разве что написанием в столбик.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста,  пример (одно-два стихотворения из хороших) и скажите в двух словах, что там «насладительного».  Может, я тоже втянусь…